# what are the possible values of the total spin S for a system of three electrons?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin

I thought given that electrons have spin $\pm \frac{1}{2}$, the values would be $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. $\frac{3}{2}$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{3}{2}$.
I have been told this is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Total spin of system of two spin-$1/2$ particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262221/total-spin-of-system-of-two-spin-1-2-particles)

Comment: of possible related interest,  https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node312.html

Answer (score 3):

Total spin is zero or positive. You are confusing $S$ and $m_S$.

Comment: This could be improved by discussing **why** this is so.  A single $e^-$ can have spin $-\frac{1}{2}$ which sure "looks" negative!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No, it can't. You, too, are confusing $S$ and $m_S$.

Comment: that was my point:  toss in some text to explain those two terms and how they are related.

Comment: Why should I? All you have to do is read the first section of the wikipedia article, or _any_ other article on spin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Quantum_number